# Strange results from the xquery ceiling function

Tags: vb.net, xpath, xquery

I am working on a VB.Net app running on .Net framework 2.0.50727.3603

When I fire off this xquery statement I get 56, but would expect 55:

```
ceiling(.55*100)
```

I am only seeing weird results on .55 and .56 as you can see my results below:

```
ceiling(.50*100) = 50
ceiling(.51*100) = 51
ceiling(.52*100) = 52
ceiling(.53*100) = 53
ceiling(.54*100) = 54
ceiling(.55*100) = 56 (would expect 55)
ceiling(.56*100) = 57 (would expect 56)
ceiling(.57*100) = 57
ceiling(.58*100) = 58
ceiling(.59*100) = 59
ceiling(.64*100) = 64
ceiling(.65*100) = 65
ceiling(.66*100) = 66
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?  Is this a bug in xquery?

Here is the basic gist of my code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Dim objXPathNavigator As XPathNavigator
evaluateExpression = objXPathNavigator.Evaluate(objXPathExpression)
```

Comment: You must accept the answer -- this is the official and expected form of gratitude at SO. To do so, just click on the green check-mark next to the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT/XPath 1.0 has a single number type, a double precision floating point type that is the same as the VB.NET Double. If you run

```
Dim doubleArray As Double() = {0.5, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59}
For Each d As Double In doubleArray
    Console.WriteLine("d: {0}; d * 100: {1}; Math.Ceil(d * 100): {2}", d, d * 100, Math.Ceiling(d * 100))
Next
```

with .NET you will find similar oddities to the one you find with your XPath evaluation.

So the problem is the limited precision of that number type in XPath 1.0 (or other languages), the decimal representation (e.g. 0.55) is finite but the binary representation might not be. If you need better precision you need to consider to move to XPath 2.0, currently only supported by third party products like Saxon 9 or XQSharp, there you can then use the xs:decimal type instead of the number type.

Comment: Perfect explanation Martin, much appreciated!  It looks like I may need to look into an XPath 2.0 upgrade.